# Getting domain name from URL issue

Tags: javascript

I need some JavaScript help I have the following function

```
domain: function(){
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = this.url;
return a.hostname;
}
```

Which is great but when this.url is something like google.com (without the http or www) my return is localhost
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to pick up the current domain?

Comment: What exactly you want to get back? Can you make an example please

Comment: I'm trying to get back either alphalab.org or www.dreamitventures.com

Comment: Basically the host name or domain name. Everything works fine if the input is a full url IE http://alphalab.org but if I input just alphalab.org I get localhost

Comment: check "this" ; with document.URL your code is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the protocol if it's missing, that way your URL will always be valid

```
domain: function(d){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = this.url.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\//) ? this.url : 'http://' + this.url;
    return a.hostname;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Lfm96xkr/)

If the url passed is just `google.com`  without a protocol, it's considered a relative URL, so the anchor ends up as

```
<a href="http://localhost/google.com"></a>
```

while if the URL is absolute and contains the protocol, it ends up as

```
<a href="http://google.com"></a>
```

That's why you have to prepend a protocol if it's missing.

Comment: Can u explain how his problem relates to `localhost` ? I dont see any correlation.

Answer (score 0):

To get the complete URL, use this,

```
var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
```